# Add prefix to every row of a column if it doesn't contain it

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame dt:

```
dt <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),value=c("a","_b","c"))
```

Now I want to add prefix _ to every 'value' that does not start with _, so the resulting data frame shall be

```
id, value
1,  _a
2,  _b
3,  _c
```

I know that I can use substr function to check if a value starts with _, but I don't want to do it with a loop. I want to use apply functions. How do I proceed? I'm new to apply functions by the way.

---Edit: thanks all for your solutions. Sorry but I over-simplified my real case. In my real case, I have to add prefix _ to values that do not start with &, different symbols.
---Edit2: Just realize it's the same. The following will do

```
dt$value <- gsub("^([^&].*)", "_\\1", dt$value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option...

```
dt$value <- gsub("^([^_].*)", "_\\1", dt$value)

dt
  id value
1  1    _a
2  2    _b
3  3    _c
```

The first regex looks for the start of a string followed by something that is not `_`, plus any following characters, and replaces it with the second regex, which is `_` plus the capture group from the first regex.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `sub` to match character that is not a `_` (`[^_]`) from the beginning (`^`) of the string, capture it as a group (`(...)`) and replace it with the `_` followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
levels(dt$value) <- sub("^([^_])", "_\\1", levels(dt$value))
dt$value
#[1] _a _b _c
#Levels: _b _a _c
```

Answer (score 1):

Dummy solution, but works... Replace beginning of **every** string with `_` and if there are two `_` (`__`) then return only one.

```
dt$value <- sub("__", "_", sub("^", "_", dt$value))
dt$value
#[1] "_a" "_b" "_c"
```